# .Net Mobile Service Back-End for Notification Hub

Tags: azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, cross-platform, azure-notificationhub

I am currently writing a mobile application with Xamarin for Android and will be adding iOS once my company purchases a Mac so that I can start developing the iOS portion.  I am currently trying to write a .Net Mobile Services back-end for Azure Notification Hub that will allow me to register the devices from the back end as well as send push notification to a specific user, and/or all users.

I have followed the Azure documentation all the way through [Getting Started With Notification Hub](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-notification-hubs-android-get-started/) and have successfully performed a single platform push. Moving beyond this example however is where I get stuck.  Every example beyond this point completely drops Android support and only focuses on Windows Phone and iOS.  I have watched a few Channel 9 videos regarding this subject and again it's all Windows Phone, Windows 8, and iOS based.

Does anyone have an example of a .Net Mobile Service back-end for Azure Notification Hub that will register the device to the notification hub from the back-end?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have sample code on GitHub yet, but here's a gist of how to get NotificationHub working on Android.

```c#
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Notifications;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class AndroidNotificationHub
{
    private readonly NotificationHubClient _hubClient;

    public AndroidNotificationHub()
    {
        const string cn = "YourConnectionStringHere";
        const string hubPath = "YourHubPathHere";
        _hubClient = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(cn, hubPath);
    }

    public async Task<RegistrationDescription> Register(string platform, string installationId, string registrationId, string userName)
    {
        // Get registrations for the current installation ID.
        var regsForInstId = await _hubClient.GetRegistrationsByTagAsync(installationId, 100);

        var updated = false;
        var firstRegistration = true;
        RegistrationDescription registration = null;

        // Check for existing registrations.
        foreach (var registrationDescription in regsForInstId)
        {
            if (firstRegistration)
            {
                // Update the tags.
                registrationDescription.Tags = new HashSet<string>() { installationId, userName };

                // We need to handle each platform separately.
                switch (platform)
                {
                    case "android":
                        var gcmReg = registrationDescription as GcmRegistrationDescription;
                        gcmReg.GcmRegistrationId = registrationId;
                        registration = await _hubClient.UpdateRegistrationAsync(gcmReg);
                        break;
                }
                updated = true;
                firstRegistration = false;
            }
            else
            {
                // We shouldn't have any extra registrations; delete if we do.
                await _hubClient.DeleteRegistrationAsync(registrationDescription);
            }
        }

        // Create a new registration.
        if (!updated)
        {
            switch (platform)
            {
                case "android":
                    registration = await _hubClient.CreateGcmNativeRegistrationAsync(registrationId, new[] { installationId, userName });
                    break;
            }
        }

        return registration;
    }

    // Basic implementation that sends a notification to Android clients
    public async Task<bool> SendNotification(int id, string from, string text, string tag)
    {
        try
        {
            var payload = new
            {
                data = new
                {
                    message = new
                    {
                        // these properties can be whatever you want
                        id,
                        from,
                        text,
                        when = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("s") + "Z"
                    }
                }
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload);

            await _hubClient.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync(json, tag);

            return true;
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
            // This is expected when an APNS registration doesn't exist.
            return false;
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> ClearRegistrations(string userName)
    {
        // Get registrations for the current installation ID.
        var regsForInstId = await _hubClient.GetRegistrationsByTagAsync(userName, 100);

        // Check for existing registrations.
        foreach (var registrationDescription in regsForInstId)
        {
            // We shouldn't have any extra registrations; delete if we do.
            await _hubClient.DeleteRegistrationAsync(registrationDescription);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Your Android client will need to call your backend's registration API during startup. I have an MVC action for this.

```c#
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(string platform, string installationId, string registrationId, string userName)
{
    try
    {
        var hub = new AndroidNotificationHub();
        var registration = await hub.Register(platform, installationId, registrationId, userName);
        return Json(registration);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Content(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Once the mobile client has registered, you can then start sending notifications from your backend, by calling the `SendNotification` method.

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Hello @Kiliman, what kind information of `installationId` value that we sent to Register function?

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles across this, it looks like installationId is just an app specific value that just gets used as a tag so nothing critical to the registration.